# Resulting space of this map

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>
> Let g: $\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $g\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ) =x_{1}+x_{2}^{2}$.
> Let ~ be the equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $x\sim y$ iff $g\left ( x \right )=g\left ( y \right )$.
> What is the resulting space?

I would like to request some hints or help in kick starting this question. To be clear, no solutions should be given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: pick a value (say $5$) and see what $g(x_1,x_2)=5$ actually means.

Comment: @Arthur It seems to resemble a circle.

Comment: What is the relevant equation?

Comment: What do you mean by relevant equation?
What I have: $x_{2}=\sqrt(5-x_{1})$

Comment: I would probably turn it over: $x_1=-x_2^2+5$, which is a sideways parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us check when

$$g(x)=g(y)\iff x_1+x_2^2=y_1+y_2^2\iff x_1-y_1=(y_2-x_2)(y_2+x_2)$$

Two simple solutions are $\;x_1=y_1,\,x_2=y_2\;$, and **also** $\;x_1=y_1,\,x_2=\color{red}-y_2\;$ . So you already have that the equivalence class of a general point $\;(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\;$ contains *at least* the points $\;(x,y),\,(x,-y)\;$, so in the quotient space both upper and lower semiplanes will be identified...

Try to follow from here.

Comment: Let me try to take it from here. Do you know of any good practice questions available online with regards to equivalence relation and equivalence classes? Unfortunately, I was thrown into topology without any background in real analysis.

Comment: In many universities nowadays, that stuff about relations, equivalence relations and etc. is covered in basic courses like discrete mathematics, set theory or something like that. One is supposed to know this *before* getting into general topolgy. But no problem: look in your school's library, or even internet, for books/articles/notes in discrete mathematics, or relations, etc. It is very useful, beautiful and really not that hard.

Comment: So i have arrived as you did.
I have$ (x_{1},x_{2})=(y_{1},y_{2})$ and  $(x_{1},x_{2})=(y_{1},-y_{2})$ 
However, the equivalence relation is giving me a bit of a problem. I think I should use what I have to link them back to the equivalence relation defined .

Comment: Take for example the point $\;(1,2)\;$ Besides $\;(1,2),\,(1,-2)\;$ , what other points are in its equivalence class?:$$(1,2)\sim(x,y)\iff5=x+y^2\iff x=5-y^2$$As already mentioned in other answers, this is a horizontal parabola openning leftwards, and thus *exactly* this points belong to $\;[(1,2)]\;$  since
$$(x,y)\;\text{belongs to this parabola}\;\iff x=5-y^2\iff x+y^2=5=1+2^2$$ Final idea: every point of $\;\Bbb R^2/\sim\;$ can be identified, if you choose so, with the vertex of these parabolas, which can be **any real number**, as you can check. Any more and you'll already get a solution

Comment: So basically, given $x+y^{2}$=c, there is a range of values x and y in the real number that satisfies the equation $x+y^{2}$=c and the point (x,y) on the parabola are contained in the equivalence class.
If c changes, so does the range of points (x,y) that satisfies $x+y^{2}$=c.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $g$ is onto and continuous

Comment: "I would like to request some hints or help in kick starting this question. To be clear, no solutions should be given."

Comment: Scaled down to a hint. - But one should be aware of the notorious examples in Jänich, where two awfully similar equivalence relations lead to totally different quotient spaces ...